# How to format price based on currency code

Tags: magento-1.9, currency, magento1.9.2.3

How can I change format a price with giving some specific `currency code`?

I search it on google but only thing which I find is to format price based on selected currency.

But I want to format that price with a **specific currency**.

Is there is any way to do that??

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Comment: `Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency('EUR')->toCurrency($price); ` did you tried that

Comment: No just tried it.. and works fine! If you can add it as a answer then i can mark it as accept and upvote to you for all community users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can format price with below code.

```
$price=10;
$symbol=Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency('EUR')->getSymbol();
$fromatprice=str_replace($symbol,'',Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency('EUR')->toCurrency($price));
```

Comment: can you tell me that how can i remove currency code from the result??

Comment: added the solution hope work for you..

Comment: Really you are very intelligent. Thanks for your help